# Get current view from finger swipe in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, touch, touch-event

In my application I have multiple small views joined together to form a big canvas. Im properly getting the touch begin/moved/ended events for each of those views separately. What I want now is this that if I touch at view1 and drag my finger out of view1 and into the territory of view2 without lifting my finger up, I want the view2 to somehow get a notification that I'm now in this view i.e. view2. Thanks.

Comment: You may be better off using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on the view containing the smaller views. As you process swipe events on the larger view, you can send messages to the associated smaller views.

Comment: thanks for the direction. let me try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using touchesMoved method. Here's the code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
CGPoint nowPoint = [touches.anyObject locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"%f, %f", nowPoint.x, nowPoint.y);

NSArray *viewsToCheck = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *v in viewsToCheck)
{
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[CharacterTile class]])
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(v.frame, nowPoint))
        {
            CharacterTile *ctTemp = (CharacterTile *)v;
            //perform your work with the subview.
        }
    }
}
}
```

where CharacterTile are the subviews added on self.view.
CGRectContainsPoint tells if the point touched by user is inside a view or not.